# When does the ground state energy continuously depend on a parameter?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, schrodinger-operators

Given a family of Schrödinger operators $H_\gamma=-\Delta+V_\gamma$, under which condition is the map $\gamma\mapsto\inf\sigma(H_\gamma)$ continuous?

This is surely the case for many textbook examples, where not only the ground state but also the wave functions are continuous in the parameter. In general, this is false, even if the dependence seems pretty continuous. Counterexamples are Smilansky-type models, for example the regular version by [Exner and Barseghyan](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/55/4/10.1063/1.4870602). However, so far, I have not found any relevant result on this question.

My a very vague conjecture on a sufficient condition is, that each $H_\gamma$ being bounded below (not uniformly, just so that the map is well-defined), $\gamma\mapsto V_\gamma$ being continuous and some condition on the domain like esa on same domain or something similar, because then one can hope to do approximation arguments. However, I was not able to obtain any rigorous result.

Comment: The general reference where there are such results is Kato, perturbation theory of linear operators.

Comment: An easy remark is that the bottom of the spectrum can't move by more than $\|V-V_{\gamma}\|_{\infty}$ (if indeed the potentials are uniformly close). For more sophisticated results, I would try to use min-max.